# Different compile-time behavior in arrow function vs function in TypeScript interface

Tags: typescript

Suppose the following simplified TypeScript snippet:

```js
interface MyInterface {
    callbackLambda: (value: string) => void;
    callbackFunction(value: string): void;
}

type MyType = "MyValue";

const myObject: MyInterface = {
    callbackLambda: (value: MyType): void => {
        console.log(value);
    },
    callbackFunction: (value: MyType): void => {
        console.log(value);
    }
};

myObject.callbackLambda("MyValue");
myObject.callbackFunction("MyValue");
```

This code doesn't compile because TypeScript says:

```
Type '(value: MyType) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: string) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"MyValue"'.
```

So, it looks like the function definition compiles fine but the arrow function definition doesn't.

Here's a [repro playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwFgAoZc5BOAG2oCNEBrAGTgFs6ATOALmQAoAbjQCuEPgGcwUUAHMAlMgC8APmSCA9sE4BuUhUo16TAGIiQCMMA0gho8cikyQCvpu16SAX1Kkw6AAcUDAAVQJQlZAAiDAA1eyjPUgQbKWQ2dAB5OgArCEs+DGxIWEQIwn0KKloGBBZ2Ll4BYWoxQvQwoPk3LU5lNWIyAyrUjWoIADpqDVk7Voh5TwMvABpK8mrjOrMLKxs+Oba0DvDu9V7+iqHhylHxqZnDhaWKH28kkgzsvMsJzdr6hxuPwYuh4vMootSF9cvkwH8jACdpZrLZQeCxJCdEA).

I couldn't find the information in the documentation and my initial thought was that it should compile fine. Can anybody explain (and find the relevant documentation) why the function definition compiles fine and not the arrow function in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the `strictFunctionTypes` flag? ([doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types))

> Under `--strictFunctionTypes` function type parameter positions are checked contravariantly instead of bivariantly. [...] The stricter checking applies to all function types, except those originating in method or constructor declarations. Methods are excluded specifically to ensure generic classes and interfaces (such as `Array<T>`) continue to mostly relate covariantly.

If so, I think the reason is that indeed `A => C` is not a subtype of `B => C` just because `A` is a subtype of `B` (covariance).
Actually, `A => C` is a supertype of `B => C` if `A` is a subtype of `B` (contravariance).

If it sounds strange, suppose you have a constant `washAnimal` of type `Animal => void`. You can't assign a function `Dog => void` to it, even if `Dog ≤ Animal`, because you would not be able to call `washAnimal` passing a `Cat`.

[Here](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance) and [here](https://dev.to/codeozz/how-i-understand-covariance-contravariance-in-typescript-2766) you can find explanations of covariance/contravariance that are better than mine.

Comment: I had found the link about variance in the TypeScript doc but couldn't figure out why an arrow function would be any different than a regular function. I guess the piece of information that was missing is the TypeScript compiler flag (used to not break the existing DOM and other existing inconsistencies).

In this case, the argument should always be a string and the call should always work, but it may not always be the case for other types.